# How to change the cursor icon in Piston2D / PistonWindow / GlutinWindow?

Tags: rust, window, mouse-cursor, rust-piston

Like Normal, Busy or Text Select. I want to create a desktop Windows applcation and I need to change its icon.

Answer (score 1):

Piston itself doesn't directly provide functionality for changing the cursor icon. However, in some cases piston exposes the underlying window, which does provide that functionality.

For instance you mention [`GlutinWindow`](https://docs.rs/pistoncore-glutin_window/0.68.0/glutin_window/struct.GlutinWindow.html), which I assume is `glutin_window::GlutinWindow` from the [`pistoncore-glutin_window` crate](https://crates.io/crates/pistoncore-glutin_window). It indirectly provides access to the underlying [`glutin::window::Window`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.26.0/glutin/window/struct.Window.html), by accessing the [`ctx`](https://docs.rs/pistoncore-glutin_window/0.68.0/glutin_window/struct.GlutinWindow.html#structfield.ctx) field.

The underlying [`glutin::window::Window`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.26.0/glutin/window/struct.Window.html) does have a [`set_cursor_icon()`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.26.0/glutin/window/struct.Window.html#method.set_cursor_icon) where you can specify a [`CursorIcon`](https://docs.rs/glutin/0.26.0/glutin/window/enum.CursorIcon.html).

```rust
use glutin_window::GlutinWindow;
use glutin::window::CursorIcon;

let wnd: GlutinWindow = ...;

wnd.ctx.window().set_cursor_icon(CursorIcon::Default);
wnd.ctx.window().set_cursor_icon(CursorIcon::Wait);
wnd.ctx.window().set_cursor_icon(CursorIcon::Text);
```